# How to get dyalog APL on arch?

Tags: apl

I wanna get it but can only find packs rpm and deb.

I tried re-compiling with debtap and rpmextract

```
debtap
rpmextract
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

- Install [ncurses5-compat-libs from the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ncurses5-compat-libs/)
- [Download](https://dyalog.com/download-zone.htm) for Linux (DEB) and extract the ZIP file.
- Run the following (`$` is the prompt):

  ```sh
  $ rpmextract.sh /linux_64_18.0.39712_unicode.x86_64.rpm
  $ opt/mdyalog/18.0/64/unicode/make_scripts
  $ opt/mdyalog/18.0/64/unicode/mapl
  ```
- You may want to look at [apl.wiki/Typing_glyphs_on_Linux](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Typing_glyphs_on_Linux)

Answer (score 1):

Other users have installed it on Arch and told us of their experiences:

This is the directory structure of what is installed on Linux.

/opt/mdyalog/18.0/64/Unicode

### this is where Dyalog files are installed

~/.dyalog/

### This directory has configuration files.

/usr/bin/dyalog

### This script sets environment variables and starts Dyalog.

This is what a Arch linux user has said to us in the past:
"It looks like only .deb and .rpm packages are available, which aren't supported by my system (Arch Linux). My first try was just to extract the files from the packages that would normally live in /opt.

I launched RIDE with `TERM=xterm` and used the "Start" option to launch dyalog. That worked as well.

So with this info, I launched RIDE as normal (without the TERM env var), and just added `TERM=xterm` in the "Environment Variables" box. This works well, and is a solution I'm happy with. "

Regards,

Vince